# How do I iterate through a table starting at a key position in lua?

Tags: loops, lua, lua-table

I am trying to iterate through a table but start from a position in the table using a key.

```
list = {
  "one",
  "two",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six"
}

for k = 3, v in pairs(list) do
  print("Key:" .. k .. " " .. "Value:" .. v)
end
```

`Compilation error on line 10: ...\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms\untitled.lua:10: 'do' expected near 'in'`

Answer (score 6):

For an *array-like* table (one with a [*sequence*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7)), you can use a [numeric `for`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5), with the upper bound being the length of the table.

```lua
local list = {
    "one",
    "two",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six"
}

for i = 3, #list do
    print(i, list[i])
end
```

```
3   four
4   five
5   six
```

---

Note that starting with a certain key (index) usually only makes sense given an *array-like* table - which your `list` is. The *key-value* pairs in a table have no stable order as far as `next`/`pairs` is concerned (note that `ipairs` is for operating on a *sequence*).

If the arbitrary keys in an *associative array-like* table follow a particular generation order (i.e., they are *deterministic*), it is possible to iterate through them in a stable way, but that is a specific use-case.

---

You can also write a function similar in form to `ipairs` - one that returns an *iterator* function (alongside the initial *state* and *control*) used by the [generic `for`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5), but starts from a given index.

Here is a cursory example where the iterator returns *index, value* to be assigned to the loop variables.

```lua
local function ipairsfrom(tab, n)
    return function (t, i)
        i = i + 1
        return t[i] ~= nil and i or nil, t[i]
    end, tab, n and n - 1 or 0
end

local list = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }

for index, value in ipairsfrom(list, 3) do
    print(index, value)
end
```

```
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

There are *many* ways to write such an iterator and the function that creates it. For example, returning *value, index* might be preferred since the *value* is often more interesting, and allows us to omit the second variable (as opposed to using `for _, value in`).

```lua
local function ipairsfrom(t, i)
    i = i and i - 1 or 0
    return function ()
        i = i + 1
        return t[i], i
    end
end

for value, index in ipairsfrom({ 'a', 'b', 'c' }, 2) do
    print(index, value)
end
```

```
2   b
3   c
```